# How to I highlight that I am deputed at client location since I joining my company?

Tags: software-development, clients, appraisal

I am deputed at client location from very first day I joined my current Employer. Now it's time for my yearly appraisal. So how do I show it as a positive point and highlight it as positive point to bargain in my raise.

Since joining I have been deputed to two different clients. The last client was highly impressed with me and even offered me job. And he was keep extending my time there. When I joined there I was the only person of my technology and worked on project from scratch and even help in hiring other developer. 
Same goes with my current client location initially they asked for 3 months and now they have extended it for 3 more months and I am confident even after these 3 months I will be asked to stay here more. Here I have learned new technology and worked on ongoing project without any proper KT or introduction to new technology.

So how do I show it as positive point to bargain in my pay raise. So my employer can't deny.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Uhm, if you have been doing a great job and the client is so impressed with you that they kept extending your deputation, then I guess your manager would know about it already?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'deputed'? It is an English word, but [the meaning doesn't seem to be relevant to your situation.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deputed)

Answer (score 1):

Your employer is already aware of your achievements, so you already have it as  positive point in your favour.

The clients and employer will communicate as a matter of course. So you treat it as any other work.

Answer (score 1):

Deputed would not be used like that in the US.

The good news is that in a downsizing if you are bringing in revenue you will be last to go.

Your employer can still deny your raise. Point out that you have good customer satisfaction and have stayed billable. If that is not a good reason for a raise I don't know what is.